# Download distribution of Jetty 6

Tags: jetty

Looks like after migration to Eclipse, the lowest version of Jetty available is 7.

Does anybody know any link which I could use to download Jetty 6 distribution?

http://archive.eclipse.org/jetty/index.html doesn't have it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can still download jetty-6 from the archived Codehaus website:

http://web.archive.org/web/20150506133523/http://dist.codehaus.org/jetty/

(really though, we have released Jetty 9.x now...look into updating, if you need help with that ping us on the dev lists)

Comment: I suspect the parent, like us, cannot afford the re-test effort that may be required for a move to a newer version.  Our software has some very old filters, extensions, a custom start.jar configuration, and things may go wrong in a subtle way not easily found by quick browsing.  Even minor updates to the libraries are frowned upon by management if not security-related or a bug-fix.

Comment: I understand and have seen this plenty, though help is available through Webtide and we have assisted a number of folks update.

Comment: Jetty 6 was EOL'd in 2010, it has no updates / fixes since then, making it no longer safe to use for a publicly accessible web site.

Comment: Hadoop still depends on Jetty 6 and servlet 2.5. Therefore any yarn application must use jetty 6.  I could hardly the document for jetty 6.

Comment: Codehaus is dead FYI.